# I am trying to plot Donut pie chart using matplotlib, but the inner circle and out pie circle doesn't seem like to start at the center

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

using this code to generate pie chart

```
df.STATUS.value_counts(sort=True).plot.pie(colors = colors, center=(0,0),explode = explode, autopct='%1.1f%%', pctdistance=0.85)
#draw circle
centre_circle = plt.Circle((0,0),0.95,fc='black')
```

Output:

[image: Donut pie chart]

Comment: I don't know that the few lines you've posted really recreate that image... Those small details are probably important for figuring out what went wrong so try to create a [mcve] with fake data (i.e. `df = pd.DataFrame({'STATUS': np.random.choice(list('abcde'), 1000)})` )that fully reproduces the problem with all the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try plotting a fake `pie` as following:

```
ax = df.STATUS.value_counts(sort=True).plot.pie(colors = colors, center=(0,0),explode = explode, autopct='%1.1f%%', pctdistance=0.85)
ax.pie([1], colors='k', radius=0.5);
```

which creates something like this:

[image]